Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'graphql') when using AWS Amplify in Next.js
Here's a refined version of your Stack Overflow question with properly formatted code:

Title:
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'graphql') when using AWS Amplify in Next.js"
Body:
Introduction:
I'm working on a Next.js application that uses AWS Amplify to interact with a DynamoDB table. The app allows users to fetch and create todos. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to fetch todos from DynamoDB.
Error Description:
I'm seeing the following error in my console:
Error fetching todos: 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'graphql')
    at fetchTodos (index.js:24:32)
    at eval (index.js:16:7)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23184:26)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24960:13)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24925:9)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24912:7)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24900:3)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27073:3)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:27018:14)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26969:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26716:5)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26151:3)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:12042:22)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:25685:13)

Relevant Code:
Here is the relevant part of my index.js file:
import { Amplify, API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from '../src/aws-exports';
import { listTodos } from '../src/graphql/queries';
import { createTodo } from '../src/graphql/mutations';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuthenticator, Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

function Home() {
  const { user, signOut } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      fetchTodos();
    }
  }, [user]);

  const fetchTodos = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTodos));
      console.log('Fetched todos:', result);
      if (result.data && result.data.listTodos && result.data.listTodos.items) {
        setTodos(result.data.listTodos.items);
      } else {
        setTodos([]);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching todos:', err);
      setError('Error fetching todos');
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const addTodo = async () => {
    if (todo.trim() === '') return;
    try {
      const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createTodo, { input: { name: todo } }));
      console.log('Created todo:', result);
      if (result.data && result.data.createTodo) {
        setTodos([...todos, result.data.createTodo]);
      }
      setTodo('');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error creating todo:', err);
      setError('Error creating todo');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 flex flex-col items-center py-6">
      {user ? (
        <>
          <div className="bg-blue-50 p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md mb-6 w-full max-w-md text-center">
            <h1 className="text-lg font-bold mb-2">Hello {user.username}</h1>
            <button
              onClick={signOut}
              className="px-4 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white rounded-lg hover:bg-red-600"
            >
              Sign out
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg p-6 w-full max-w-md">
            <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">ToDo List</h1>
            <div className="flex mb-4">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={todo}
                onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="New ToDo"
                className="flex-grow p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-l-lg"
              />
              <button
                onClick={addTodo}
                className="p-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-r-lg hover:bg-blue-600"
              >
                Add ToDo
              </button>
            </div>
            {loading ? (
              <p className="text-center">Loading...</p>
            ) : error ? (
              <p className="text-center text-red-500">{error}</p>
            ) : todos.length === 0 ? (
              <p className="text-center">0 available</p>
            ) : (
              <ul className="list-disc list-inside">
                {todos.map((item) => (
                  <li key={item.id} className="p-2 border-b border-gray-300">{item.name}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            )}
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <Authenticator />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;

What I Have Tried:

Verified that AWS Amplify is correctly configured in _app.js.
Confirmed that aws-exports.js is correctly generated and imported.
Ensured that GraphQL queries (listTodos) and mutations (createTodo) are correctly defined and imported.
Checked IAM role permissions to ensure they include the necessary DynamoDB actions.

Environment Details:

Node.js version: v14.17.0
Next.js version: 10.2.0
AWS Amplify version: 4.3.0
AWS AppSync GraphQL Endpoint: Configured via aws-exports.js

Request for Help:
What could be causing the Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'graphql') error? How can I properly configure AWS Amplify to interact with my GraphQL API?
